# Как создать блок после выделенного текста?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция которая получает выделенный на странице текст:

```js
$('*').on('mouseup', function() {
        let mytext = getSelectedText();
    console.log( mytext );
});

var getSelectedText = function() {
    let text = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
      
  return text; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>I won't beg for your love: it's laid Safely to rest, let the earth settle... Don't expect my jealous letters Pouring in to plague your bride. But let me, nevertheless, advise you: Give her my poems to read in bed, Give her my portraits to keep - it's wise to Be kind like that when newly-wed.</p>
```

Я хочу сделать чтобы после того как текст был выделен, чтобы в конце выделения создавался  блок, в котором я размещу информацию.

Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: этот блок должен разрывать строку или появится как меню из-под правой кнопки мыши?

Comment: Разрывать строку не надо

Comment: Но тогда, проще всего:
1. Получите координаты мыши на момент окончания выделения текста (mouseup )
2. Нарисуйте там блок.

Comment: Не особо ещё разбираюсь в это) буду очень благодарен если набросаете воспроизводимый пример

Comment: В чем именно вы не разбираетесь?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/coordinates Там ничего сложного нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте блок и например кнопку его закрытия `<div class="block"> Я блок с текстом <div class="close">X</div></div>` и задайте этим элементам нормальное позиционирование, т.е. самому блоку absolute, а кнопке закрытия например relative и не забудьте скрыть этот элемент в CSS display: none
2. там где слушаете маус ап, проверьте, приходит ли что-то в mytext, чтобы этот блок не появлялся при простом клике `if(mytext !== '')`
   и если да, получите координаты мыши после выделения текста

```
let a = e.clientX+'px';
let b = e.clientY+'px';
```

3. Отрисуйте по ним блок, вернув ему display в 'block'

Всё вроде бы.